# Google+ sign-in works always in Chrome, but fails after time in IE and FF

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, google-plus, google-oauth

I've implemented Google+ sign-in on my site, but with limited success.  On initial authorization, the sign-in flow works correctly to the best of my knowledge (I'm not sure if the double GET requests to Google are normal, but authentication works).  After `immediate_failed`, I clicked the sign in button and Google returned an object with OAuth tokens, one-time use code, etc.  Before I continue, I should clarify that the object logged is simply the `authResult` returned by Google.

[image: initial authentication, FF]

However, after an indeterminate amount of time (but less than the hour of the OAuth tokens), and usually after I've signed in and out at least once to verify that it works, FF begins behaving oddly.  The below error occurs after being signed in for a period of time (not sure if it would still happen while I'm signed out).

[image: error authentication, FF]

Regardless of what I do, whether it's to sign in or sign out, Google consistently returns the `error="user_signed_out"` object (and calls my callback function twice).  As you can see, after clicking the sign-in button, Google does give me a successful object, but immediately returns an unsuccessful one.

This persists until I revoke access on Google's end and re-authorize my app.  Rinse and repeat, without fail.  However, this is not the case in Chrome.  Every time I've tested, Google returns a successful object, unless, of course, I'm signed out.  IE is an interesting case: it calls my callback twice, as in FF, and each call returns the same `error="user_signed_out"`.  When I click the sign-in button, IE receives a successful object from Google (singular) and doesn't output anything more, but a page refresh brings everything back to square one.

Now, some code samples.  Perhaps I've overlooked something.

Inserted into the head of my pages:

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
    console.log(authResult);  // The thing that's outputting all the unfortunate debugging data
    if(authResult['status']['signed_in'])   {
        $.ajax({
            data:   {
                code: authResult['code']
            },
            type: "POST",
            url:"/authentication/gplus"
        }).done(function()  {
            // Hide the button, change the menu, etc.
            //window.setTimeout(logout(), authResult['expires_in']*1000);  
            // ^ Auto-logout.  Attempt to test if errors were from invalid OAuth tokens, but not the case.  Is, in fact, broken, as the logout function is called immediately (don't know why).
        });
    }   else    {
        // Show the button, menu, etc.
    }
}

function logout()   { // Call logout script back on the server to unset session variables
    $.ajax({
        url:"/authentication/gplus/logout"
    });
    gapi.auth.logout();
}
```

The PHP at `/authentication/gplus` largely follows the examples in the Google API Client Library for PHP.  It's rather long, and I believe it to be irrelevant to this question, as the error is in the javascript (I tested the app without the PHP, and the same problem persisted), so I won't post it.

My script includes are exactly as the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) displays them, and, again, I don't believe it's relevant to my problem.  My sign button is rendered similarly.

My question, I hope, is clear.  What?  It makes sense that Chrome would be the one to work (it's a Googly process, after all), but what the $^&@ is happening with FF and IE?  Is it a me problem, or is it a Google problem (I suspect me, but not sure)?  There are similar questions out there, but this seems to be an aggregation of many of them, and the ones that I've found have either had no responses or solutions that didn't work for me.

Thank you especially for your time, if you've read this far.  I do apologize for my question's length, but I wish to be clear.

Comment: Do you experience this when you don't interleave sign-in from one of these other browsers? Or does this only happen when you've signed-in from one of these other browsers after signing into the other browser?

Comment: Assuming you were asking whether the error happens when I'm signed in to the website in multiple browsers.  No, since I do my main testing in FF.  Once I notice the error, I'll test it in other browsers, and by that point, I'm "signed out" according to Google.

Comment: Thanks, @Will. That strikes out my only hypothesis. I'll leave answering this question to the experts on this subject, then.

Comment: Good point, though.  I re-verified, and no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have tried this earlier when I got different responses for each browser, but...  For some reason, cookies were screwing things up.  I cleared my cookies on FF, and everything started working.  I have no idea why this is, or which ones were the problem, but everything appears to be working now.